# Export job from Jenkins 1 to Jenkins 2

Tags: jenkins

We have a working Jenkins 1 instance and we want to copy the existing jobs to Jenkins 2. We don't want to upgrade the Jenkins 1 because we want to keep our old/existing environment too.

I remember we can just copy the `jobs/` directory (to export from Jenkins 1 to Jenkins 1). We will probably copy one job each time so we can correct it more easily when something is going wrong.

But is this way of working also possible to copy a job on Jenkins 1 to Jenkins 2 or do we need to use another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Job Import Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin) will do the trick for you.

Comment: Does it support migration from 1 to 2? Is there any difference on file structure or something between 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes it does. You can replicate the same structure in Jenkins 2, that you have in Jenkins 1.